# Can Dart function accept scoped arguments?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can Dart accepts arguments with hinted and scoped parameter?

example :

```
types PostType = {
  "HOT": 1,
  "NEW": 2,
  "TRENDING": 3
}


function getPost(PostType type){
 if(type == PostType.TRENDING) {
    // do something
 }
 // some code
}

Posts posts = getPost(PostType.TRENDING);
```

Above code `getPost()` only accept PostType values.
is it possible?

Comment: Yes. I invite you to [read this](https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-dart)

Comment: @JulienLachal can the vscode IDE intellisense suggest the values? can you please show me proper example with example above? thanks

Comment: Suggest values when? I'm not using VSCode but after typing `PostType.` I guess it will offer you the types in your enum.

Comment: @JulienLachal ah yes, it's called `ENUM`! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @JulientLachal said, it's called Enum!